# Kafka connect cluster architecture in aws ecs

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, amazon-ecs, apache-kafka-connect

I have a **KAFKA CONNECT** in an **ECS SERVICE** with a single task. It has an **ASG** and an **ALB**.

I know that when I start my **ECS TASK** with my **KAFKA CONNECT**, I generate 1 **WORKER** from the **KAFKA CONNECT**. In this **WORKER** I can have several **TASKS** `tasks.max` created in the **CONNECTORS CONF**.

My reasoning is as follows: by scaling my **ECS SERVICE** to 3 **ECS TASKS**, I would have 3 **WORKERS** from **KAFKA CONNECT** and by scaling my **TASKS** `tasks.max` to 3 I would arrive at the logic of the image?

[image: ecs cluster]

If this is true, do I need any additional configuration so that the cluster is managed and the **PRODUCER** data reaches the **TOPIC** and is received by the **CONSUMER** without duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workers are the replicas of your container, yes.

Tasks can be more than workers, and are generally limited by available CPU cores or threads, but the JVM manages that logic.